# Shortest grid connection wire length

Tags: r, geospatial, shortest-path

I am constructing a microgrid, so I have to connect 12 or so houses to a central solar power source. Wiring is a major cost here, so I'm trying to come up with a configuration that minimizes wire length. It's similar but not exactly like a traveling salesman problem, because multiple wires can come out of the same source -- if it were a single wire/path, it would be exactly like the TSP.

So my question is:

Does anyone know of an algorithm to determine the shortest way to connect all points, where there is a central point that can connect an indeterminate number of the surrounding points? The final solution should resemble a graph in which *n-1* nodes have maximum two edges connecting them and one may have up to *n-1* edges? Specifically, is there a way to do this in R?

EDIT TO SHOW CODE/EFFORT

I've solved it in a relatively simple way assuming a single path. And I've solved it assuming every house is connected directly to the power source. Here is that code:

```
############ interested users Wire CalculationBommekalla Analysis
require(png)
require(grid)
require(arm)
require(DCluster)
require(ggplot2)

setwd("C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/India2014_2015/ADATS Docs/BoomekallaAnalysis")

data= read.csv("BommekallInterestedUsers.csv")
summary(data)
names(data)

data$ind = c(1:nrow(data))

##### Analysis

# Shortest Path

distFrame = data[,c("Lon.Deg", "Lat.Deg")]
dists= as.matrix(dist(distFrame, upper=TRUE))
diag(dists)=1000


current= which(data.WO$ind==11)  # sushilemma
ord = rep(current,length=nrow(data.WO))
dists[,current]=1000

for (j in c(1:(nrow(data.WO)-1))){
    current= which(dists[current,]==min(dists[current,]))
    dists[,current]=1000
    ord[j+1] = current
}

# line calculation
firstHouses= data.WO[ord,]
secondHouses= data.WO[c(ord[-1],NA),]

lines = data.frame(lonA = firstHouses$Lon.Deg, 
    latA= firstHouses$Lat.Deg, 
    lonB = secondHouses$Lon.Deg,
    latB = secondHouses$Lat.Deg)
lines= na.omit(lines)

# Spider web -- completely connected to source

ccLines = data.frame(latA = data$Lat.Deg[
    data$Name=="Sushilemma"], latB = data$Lat.Deg,
    lonA = data$Lon.Deg[data$Name=="Sushilemma"],
    lonB = data$Lon.Deg) 

# Haversine Distance -- atanh_trans() is arctan

linesRads=lines*pi/180

a= with(linesRads, sin((latB-latA)/2)^2+
    cos(latB)*cos(latA)*sin((lonB-lonA)/2)^2)
c= 2*asin(pmin(1,sqrt(a)))
lines$distance=6371*c*1000

totalDistance = sum(lines$distance)

totalCost = totalDistance*15
```

[image: Map of the village]

[image: completely connected wiring]

[image: single path wiring with a single spatial outlier left out]

Comment: Looks like a HW problem. At the very least you should post an example constructed with R code and show what efforts you have made... both in coding and searching for similar problems and appropriate algorithms.

Comment: No, BondedDust, I'm literally in an Indian village called Chintamani, Karnataka, working with an NGO to start a solar microgrid program. I'm not kidding. I've been here since August on an NSF grant.

Comment: Great. Would like to help but do still insist that it is your responsibility to post an actual example.

Comment: Posted code, now posting images

Comment: This is at least close to a [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem).